# Going through a JSON file and displaying all elements

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a JSON file that I am fetching from github. And I have certain problems. My JSON file:

```
{    "Data" : 
[        
{"Name": "Widget", "Price": "25.00", "Quantity": "5" },
{"Name": "Thing", "Price": "15.00", "Quantity": "5" },        
{"Name": "Doodad", "Price": "5.00", "Quantity": "10" } 
] }
```

Now, I am writing in a .html file and have a script section in which I want to write a JavaScript function that will allow me to go through Data from JSON and for example display the names of all the products that are there:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="form1">
                What product do you want? <input name="name" type="text" size="20">
            </form>
            <button onclick="outputprodus()">Submit
            </button>
            <button id="fetchUserDataBtn">Cauta</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="response"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('fetchUserDataBtn').addEventListener('click', fetchUserData);

            function fetchUserData(){
                fetch('Vlad.json')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(Data => {
                        console.log("salut");
                        let output = "Lista produselor din stoc"
                        output += '<ul>';
                        Data.forEach(function(Data) {
                            output += `
                                <li>
                                    ${Data.Name}
                                </li>
                            `;
                        });
                        output += '</ul>'
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = output;
                    });
            }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run it, I get the error "Data.forEach is not a function". Funny enough is that when I write my JSON file without the initial "{"Data:" and just begin immediately writing the name for all objects, this problem does not occur and I can get a list of all the names of the products using the script above. However I want to use a loop to identify certain objects using a user input I will later add. Can anyone elucidate this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate an object which is not possible. You need to iterate the array which is the `Data` property. So you need to do it like this:
`Data.Data.forEach(function(Data) {` or `Data['Data'].forEach(function(Data) {`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Ah, yeah, you got it mate. I used the first option and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch for that!

Answer (score 0):

forEach is a method for arrays, not objects. What your code does is that it tries to forEach through the JSON itself. So you need to get the objects "Data" value which is the acutal array 
 You can acheiv that throught `objectName.propertyName` or `objectName["propertyName"]`

*so your code should look this this*:

```
Data.Data.forEach(function(Data) {
  output += `<li>${Data.Name}</li>`;
});
```

or

```
Data["Data"].forEach(function(Data) {
  output += `<li>${Data.Name}</li>`;
});
```

`objectName["propertyName"]` can be useful when trying to access keys that look this this: `"Data-new"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mate! I keep forgetting how to "treat" json files as it's my first time working with them.